# Auto-generated page file

Tags: wordpress, layout, plugins, elementor, wordpress-plugin-creation

Created a page

[image: MySite]

The address bar says `digitalelectronics.ru/elementor-7/`. But there is no such folder in the site. Tell me which file contains the template of the file displayed in the browser under the address `digitalelectronics.ru/elementor-7`. Looked at a temporary file (needed, searched)

[image: ScreenshotOfMySite]

Then I searched for the file by the text found in the chrome code (see immediately above) -

[image: SearchingInWordpressFiles]

but found nothing

[image: Text]

Tell me how to find the Elementor file displayed in the website builder?

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is not a folder, it is the permalink of the post/page. Wordpress rewrites the url path based on your settings:
[image]

You can change that slug when you edit a post/page.

Classic Editor:
[image]

Gutenberg Editor:
[image]

[See here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/) for more info about permalinks.

To find out what php template is responsible for the page you are viewing have a look at the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). It would usually be `single.php` if it is a post or `page.php` if it is a page.

Alternatively you can use a plugin [like this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/), or similar, that would always show what templates make up the page you are currently viewing.

Comment: And how to find the path to the file being edited in Elementor (specifically to Elementor, not WordPress) (see https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1177084/%d0%9f%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%83-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b and https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1177625/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-link-elementor-config-document-urls-permalink

Comment: Elementor is page builder for Wordpress. An addon plugin to help you build the content of a Wordpress post/page. I would suggest to start with basic Wordpress pages first or have a look at Elementor's Getting started (https://elementor.com/getting-started/) and Knowledgebase (https://docs.elementor.com/)